# How to use the content of a list of objects as a condition for a loop to modify a dataframe in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, genetics

Here is my question. I have a "list" of objects and a data frame as heads below:

```
                 0
0  hsa-let-7f-2-3p
1  hsa-let-7f-2-5p
2   hsa-miR-105-3p
3   hsa-miR-105-5p
6  hsa-miR-106a-3p
```

And

```
               Gene_ID  miRNA_family_ID
1452449   NM_001038707  hsa-let-7f-2-3p
14537388     NM_058241  hsa-let-7f-2-3p
14540512     NM_078467  hsa-let-7f-2-3p
15618969     NM_153051  hsa-let-7f-2-3p
5500627   NM_001184880  hsa-let-7f-2-3p
```

Their len.index are diferent
For the "list"

```
`>>> len(miRNAs.index)`
```

175

```
>>> len(Alvos_Mir.index)
```

18744

their boths dtypes are objects.

What I really need to do is to use the content of the list to compare with the column `miRNA_family_ID` to save in a `.csv` file all the Gene_ID that has it as it's `miRNA`.

What I tried to do was:

```
for i in range(len(miRNAs)):
        GenesAlvo_miRNA = [Alvos_Mir['miRNA_family_ID'] == miRNAs[i]];
        colunas_interesse_to_save = GenesAlvo_miRNA.ix[:, ['Gene_ID']];
        #here i put the values.tolist() beacause I need the format of the output to be like (1,2,3,4,5) and not as a column
        colunas_interesse_to_save = colunas_interesse_to_save.values.tolist()
        #I need that the name of the output file is the content current being compare
        colunas_interesse_to_save.to_csv(miRNAs[i], index=False)
```

I'm geting the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
>   File "/home/beatriz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 582, in wrapper
>   raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
>   ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
> ```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to create multiple new files named as each miRNA_id contening the multiples gene_ids for each miRNA_ID.  That is I need to split the original file in multiple ones containing the rows of the columns gene_id's according to each miRNA_id. One miRNA_ID per file. Is that more clear? Thank u very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whether you want to save things in the same file or in different files, but if you wanted to save things in different files, you could try something like the following:

```
for k, v in Alvos_Mir.groupby('miRNA_family_ID'):
    if k in miRNAs: v.to_csv(k+'.csv')
```